# How to unit test using patch with a side effect with Pytest parametrize?

Tags: python-3.x, unit-testing, mocking, pytest

I'm trying to test my function that takes in 3 arguments and also contains another function which I'm trying to mock. The issue is that the mock does not cycle through the side effect; I can't 'match' the first set of values I want to test (the first parametrized arguments) with the first value in the side effect; the second set of parametrized arguments with the second value in the side effect and so forth.

I tried to use fixtures and played around with parametrize but to no avail.

## TEST CODE

```
# I go through each set of values I want to test with a different expected output
@pytest.mark.parametrize('banner, year, month, expected', [
    ('ctr', 2019, 1, r'A\path\file.csv'),
    ('mks', 2019, 1, r'B\path\file.csv'),
    ('sc', 2019, 1, r'C\path\file.csv'),
    ('atm', 2019, 1, r'D\path\file.csv')
])
@mock.patch('import.path.to.function.path_formatting')
def test_files(mock_directory_path_banner, banner, year, month, expected):
    # the mocked function always returns 'ctr'
    mock_directory_path_banner.side_effect = ['ctr', 'mww', 'fgl', 'fgl']
    result = get_loyalty_sales_files(banner, year, month)
    assert expected == result
```

In total, there are four tests. The first passes as the parameterized test uses the correct value from the mock (ctr). However the remaining tests all fail because a new mock is not called for each parameterized test. I expect that a new mock is called each time a new parameterized set of values is cycled through, but that's not the case.

Comment: Place the `mock.patch` decorator before parametrizing, or move patching inside test function instead of using decorator.

Comment: It doesn't work when I put the decorator before parametrizing or when I move the patch inside the test function and use a context manager

Comment: Hmmm - the code is incomplete, but what makes me suspicious is that 'ctr' occurs both in your parametrize-list and in the size_effect list.  For all other values of 'banner' there is no match between the values.  Could this be the reason that the test succeeds exactly for the 'ctr' case and fails for the others?  Just a guess, since you have not shown us all the relevant code parts...  Or, asked differently: are you really sure that the mock object is always the same, or is this just an assumption?

Answer (score 1):

In the file with `get_loyalty_sales_files` you have something like this

```
import path.to.function.path_formatting
```

Don't use this in the `@patch`, instead use the same path as you would import the module locally, and then append the function you want to mock:

```
@patch('path.to.file.with.get_loyalty_sales_files.path_formatting')
```

More information on how `mock.patch` works can be found [in the mock docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#where-to-patch).